# Celery pool types and concurrency

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, eventlet

I am having a hard time putting together how multi-threading concurrency works in celery.

It looks like the default type to use would be `-P eventlet`. I am assuming that `-P threads` does not work because of the GIL, and there would be no concurrency in practice.

But it also looks like (from example [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/eventlet)) I can't simply specify `-P eventlet` and start firing tasks away, I have to initiate parallel tasks via `celery.group`. And according to [this](http://www.quora.com/Celery-distributed-task-queue/What-is-the-difference-between-workers-and-processes), a multiprocess worker will never consume messages in parallel.

So, to sum up, it looks like to have true parallelization of tasks, I have to use multiprocessing. I can use eventlet, but I would have to modify how my tasks are run. My tasks are firing at random in response to external triggers, so I don't know in advance when and how many I will need to create - so it doesn't look like I can use eventlet for my use case.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've only just started experimenting with using the eventlet pool myself, but from what I can tell so far, no, you need not use group() to call your tasks to take advantage of its concurrency. I think it's just coincidence that they used it for the example. Probably the two concepts often play nice together, though. I'm still getting eventlet concurrency with tasks applied with separate apply_async() invocations inside a Python for loop, which is probably fine if you don't need the GroupResult functionality (see http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups).